# ¿Como hacer que cargue un controlador antes que la carga de un archivo js?

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor, controller, model-view-controller

Estoy realizando una pequeño tutorial guiado para una página web, estoy utilizando una librería llamada **introjs**, la cual ayuda bastante para esa tarea.

Pero tengo un pequeño problema, la página web esta creada con MVC Razor, y la parte del menú es dinámico, y se carga desde el controlador, y cuando asigno las variables para que funcione la librería **Intro**, primero se carga el **html** que el controlador por ende no me toma la libreria cuando la ejecuto.

Mi duda es ¿cómo hago para cargar de forma asíncrona la invocación de **IntroJS** con el controlador?

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de cómo lo tienes... (si subieras el código podría verlo más claramente)

Pero, para tener la ejecución de un Script de JS luego de la carga, en primera, al final de el View

```
<script src="script/myscrip.js"></script>
```

También, la función principal debe estar dentro de un Document Ready (en el documento JS, suponiendo que estás utilizando Jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
// todo tu código aquí

})
```

Si no utilizas JQuery, en Javascript puro

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // your code goes here
}, false);
```

Comment: se agradece tu ayuda, pero no se deben responder preguntas que no estan claras o son muy amplias, efectivamente falta una muestra del código que esta usando te invito a leer [answer] y de paso haz el [tour]